# Since 17/01/2019: com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchException: Error constructing stub for app

Tags: google-app-engine

Since 17/1/2019 App Engine search Java is not working for my application. Every time I try to access the Search-service I am getting the following error or exception:

> com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchException: Error constructing
>   stub for app

Any Idea why it is giving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem.

com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchException: Error constructing stub for app h~**xxxx**
at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl$4.convertException(IndexImpl.java:352) 
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:109) 
at com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:74) 
at com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:33) 
at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.search(IndexImpl.java:502)

No clue at the moment.

### Update (24 Jan 2019)

Not getting this issue from 22 Jan 2019. Based on the last update from the Google Support team, the google engineering team identified this error and they have managed to mitigate it.